# C# asynchronous delegates, thread scheduling

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm absolutely new to threads and trying to understand the very basics. I've got this code with asynchronous delegates invocation:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{      
   Action<Thread, string> action = (mainThread, name) =>
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = name;
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} starts", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
            while (true)
            {
                var input = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} catches an input. User's input is: \"{1}\""
                                  +"\nMain thread is alive = {2}",
                                  Thread.CurrentThread.Name, input, mainThread.IsAlive);
            }
        };
    action.BeginInvoke(Thread.CurrentThread,"First", null, null);
    action.BeginInvoke(Thread.CurrentThread, "Second", null, null);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

And whatever I do,  the output result always goes in the following order: First->Second->First->Second->First...

[image: output]

As far as I understand, the output order should be nondetermenistic. Bu in this case it is. How the thread queue is processed? What am I  missing? Please, explain

Comment: If you want to check multithreading try to avoid user input, i'm pretty there is a lock inside Console.readline that makes them take turn.

Comment: They are sharing the same Console.

Comment: But why can't a one thread in one slice of a time make twice print-readline-print-readline?

Comment: I didn't know that it is even safely possible to read from the console safely. Where is that documented?

Comment: @usr you can write to it safely, why not read safely too?

Comment: @I3arnon if its not documented you can't do it because you can't be sure. I just don't know whether it is guaranteed. Reading concurrently is also inherently racy. I do not see who would ever do such a thing.

Comment: @usr, [`Console`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console(v=vs.110).aspx) is documented to be thread-safe: *Thread Safety: This type is thread safe.* Of course, reading it concurrently might produce some messy data, but at least the same character won't be read twice by two threads.

Answer (score 4):

When you wait for input from the user on `var input = Console.ReadLine();` you are basically locking your threads. the first one waits for input and when received prints it. The other thread at the exact time already asked for input and waiting for it. So you get one line for each one.

If you remove the `ReadLine` and use this line instead:

```
var input = "Hamster";
```

You will get the results you want:

[image]